# cocos2d : rotate a sprite so it is oriented to the center of the screen

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, rotation, sprite

so I create a sprite every second at a random position . What I would like is that the sprite is oriented to the center of the screen. For example if I create a human body every second at a random position, I would like his head to be oriented to the center of screen . thank you :) sorry for my english I'm french :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CCPoint pos1 = [yourHuman position];
CCPoint pos2 = screenCenter;

    float theta = atan((pos1.y-pos2.y)/(pos1.x-pos2.x)) * 180 * 7 /22;

    if(pos1.y - pos2.y > 0)
    {
        if(pos1.x - pos2.x < 0)
        {
            [yourHuman setRotation:(-90-theta)];
        }
        else if(pos1.x - pos2.x > 0)
        {
            [yourHuman setRotation:(90-theta)];
        }       
    }
    else if(pos1.y - pos2.y < 0)
    {
        if(pos1.x - pos2.x < 0)
        {
            [yourHuman setRotation:(270-theta)];
        }
        else if(pos1.x - pos2.x > 0)
        {
            [yourHuman setRotation:(90-theta)];
        }
    }
```

This is done. Keep this code in a method. And use it.. :) Hope this helps..

Comment: how I do it if now I would like its feet to be oriented to the center of the screen and not its head ? What changes do I have to make please ?

Comment: There are 2 ways... 1 is add 180 to calculated angle.. 2nd is rotate the original image to 180 degree.. No need to change the angle.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
CGPoint screenCenter = ...; // set it manually or from device screen size
CGPoint direction = ccpSub (screenCenter, yourHuman.position);
yourHuman.rotation = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREE (ccpToAngle (direction));
```

I'm not sure about rotation angle, so maybe you will need

`yourHuman.rotation = -CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREE (ccpToAngle (direction));`

Comment: I have the error :No match for 'operator' in'screenCenter -@'property_reference_expr' not supported by dump ...

Comment: Greg, what are you using for the first line CGPoint screenCenter? Are you setting that to the center of the screen (or main window)?

Comment: I do : CGPoint screenCenter=ccp(240,160);

Comment: the error you're reporting above is because a point cannot be subtracted. So CGPoint - CGPoint is not possible.  Use some other way to get the 'direction'.

Comment: I used float for screenCenter but it doesn't work ? what should I do ? Can you give me a code

Comment: CGPoint delta = CGPointMake(pointB.x-pointA.x, pointB.y-pointA.y);

Comment: greg, sorry :) my mistake. write `ccpSub (screenCenter, yourHuman.position)` instead of `-`

Comment: but with this code the sprite rotate to only one direction . because my sprites appear at random position I don't them to be rotated to only on direction, but to the center of the screen,  but with your code they are all rotated to one direction. so for example if my human appear at the bottom of the screen its head is oriented to the center of the screen, but when my human appear at the top of the screen its head is oriented to the top and not to the center . you understand ?